# WPF ResourceDictionaries

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a wpf tab control which is highly customized through styles.  I have referenced those styles in a resourcedictionary "TabControlResources".  How do I reference "TabControlResources" in another resourcedictionary?.  I have a resourcedictionary called "MainViewResources" and I would like to reference the tab style from my "TabControlResources" in that resourcedictionary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary
        Source="pack://application:,,,/path/to/TabControlResources.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<other stuff...>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Good answer, but you don't need the `pack://application:,,,/` in the Source string.  In fact, that particular prefix is always superfluous in any `Application.LoadComponent` context because it is added automatically whenever a relative path is passed.